# Reopen question on how to generate a readme programmatically in Python

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed, canonical

I don't have any idea why [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64902583/generate-github-flavored-markdown-programatically-using-python) copped such a bad reception, but I'll try to improve it more if people have suggestions.

It's long, but I hope it's clear what is trying to be achieved (even if wasn't clear when the question first appeared).

Please reopen if you consider it a useful question.

Note: I asked the same question in another forum at the same time, and it generated a lot of positive interest there, so perhaps it was my initial wording of the question that people didn't like, or even that it wasn't relevant to the GitHub tag. Or maybe that Python people saw [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) code and thought the question was junk. I'm not exactly sure, to be honest.

Update: After some more research, I found [this broader question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118021/python-alternative-to-r-markdown) to which there is no answer (there *is* an answer displayed, which is helpful, but it [doesn't answer the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118021/python-alternative-to-r-markdown#comment93753239_33118733)). So it's possible that Python simply doesn't have a common pattern/convention/framework for generating GitHub markdowns programmatically (and you just have to write them manually, or use Python to write strings that can form valid Markdown).

After learning this (and with hindsight), I can see why bluntly asking

> How can a github flavored markdown document be generated in python?

would be confusing (and elicit down/close votes), since the broader tooling for [knittr-style programmatic report generation](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#knitr) doesn't seem to be common practice in Python.

Comment: It doesn't look like you asked a question. It looks like you posted an answer in the question box.

Comment: @CodyGray no!! (not you too!).. I want to know how to do the thing that I'm doing in R, in python!

Comment: @CodyGray that's what a comment on the question said at first, that I hadn't asked a question. I literally show exactly how to do it in R, and I just want to know how do I do the exact same thing in python.

Comment: @CodyGray perhaps it's the R example that throws people off? Perhaps I should remove it?

Comment: Ah. Yeah. I would recommend slimming down the question and cutting out unimportant stuff. Looks like the presentation is confusing a lot of people. ("I want to do x. I am currently doing it in R, like this <very, *very* simple presentation>. How can I achieve the same results in Python?")

Comment: @CodyGray great idea, I'll make it as simple as possible, and make the R example simpler

Comment: While editing consider clarifying how the question is more complicated than "how to write text in python".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov okay, thanks, I'll do that as well. Appreciate it

Comment: It also helps a lot if you take a stab at writing the python code and instead ask, "Where did I <expletive deleted> up?" if it doesn't work.

Comment: @user4581301 *Sometimes*, if you're asking a debugging question. Other times, wrong code just clouds the issue.

Comment: It's currently not clear what you are trying to do *concretely* – in specific, what is your desired *input* format. Markdown usually already is the input format, and one just writes it down as desired. Assume that the Python people you are asking *do not have an R toolchain available*, so just showing an R example is not as helpful as it may seem. Be aware that Python projects often use ReStructured Text (ReST) instead of Markdown; explicitly requiring Markdown output may artificially restrict results.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Interesting. Can github use ReST for the README.md file? Do you have an example?